# 0xE0434F4D Error

Tags: mfc, c++-cli

all, I have a rather frustrating issue.  The application in question has an MFC GUI that uses the classes available in the MFC Featurepack.  This GUI uses an DLL that is developed in C++\CLI.  Our company uses Cruise Control. NET (1.4.4 SP1) on Windows Server 2008 SP2 for continuous integration. Cruise Control is setup to use the version of MSBuild that comes with the 3.5 version on the framework.

The issue in question is that if I use the build that Cruise Controls creates, I receive the following error: "Unhandled exception at 0x7642fbae (kernel32.dll) in FormView.exe: 0xE0434F4D: 0xe0434f4d."  After some digging, the issue seems to be that the GUI doesn't like the C++\CLI assembly.

The "gotcha" is that if I log on to the server, and, using PowerShell, execute the same MSBuild command, the build works.  Any one have ideas?

Comment: Further information.  At codymanix's advice, I got attached VS to the process and generated the exception.  This is the error:
"Could not load file or assembly 'FormViewClassLibrary, Version=1.0.3455.29542, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0b107c4f80806626' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. "

I should mention some more.  This assembly does no go into the GAC by default.  However, I have an installer that does place it into the installer, which is built after the main executable is built.  Could there be something there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was how I was building the installer.   It was a separate solution from the project's main solution, and was thus a separate task from the primary build.  Therefore, the output assemblies got signed twice, and loader complained because the one the application wanted was no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

you could try and attach the process to the visual studio debugger.

Comment: I've tried that.  It's an exception in the kernel.  All the stuff on line states that this is a result of an exception within the CLR, and yet, the only managed object that this application uses doesn't generate a log file.